# setting map as payload in mule 3 using session values from session variables

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I have a **GET** request inbound at my localhost. I have extracted all the URI parameters from the request and stored them in session variables. Now the problem I'm facing is when I try to set map as payload using session values.

While searching for correct method to do so I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106335/setting-map-as-payload-in-mule-flow-using-mel).

The method described here is correct and it works in following case when I hard code the key-value pair.

```
<set-payload value="#[['Test' : 'hjhj' ]]"  encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Following message is printed:

```
Payload               : {Test=hjhj}
Payload Type          : java.util.HashMap
```

But when I use the same method and write the following code using session variable:

```
 <set-session-variable variableName="transactionAmount" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.amount]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>

<set-payload value="#[['Test' : #[sessionVars.transactionAmount] ]]"  encoding="UTF-8"/>
```

Message which gets printed:

```
Payload               : {Test=[1]}
Payload Type          : java.lang.String
```

Please tell me how I can overcome this problem. I'm stuck in this for long.

**NOTE: I'm using Mule 3.9**

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Why are you using session vars instead of flow vars? By default you should use flow vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the nested expression evaluators #[]

Try this:

```
<set-payload value="#[['Test' : sessionVars.transactionAmount]]" />
```